# Converting Numbers to English (1-99) in C++

Tags: c++

Trying to convert numbers into English from 1-99 but I honestly do not know what I am missing out here. Whenever I input a number like 20 it doesn't output Twenty like it should. Any help would be appreciated! :)

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    cout << "In this program we will convert integers to English" << endl;

    int Number, leftDigit, rightDigit, yes;
    yes = 1;

    string ones[] = {" Zero"
                     " One "
                     " Two  "
                     " Three "
                     " Four  "
                     " Five  "
                     " Six   "
                     " Seven "
                     " Eight "
                     " Nine  "
                     " Ten   "
                     " Eleven "
                     " Twelve  "
                     " Thirteen"
                     " Fourteen "
                     " Fifteen  "
                     " Sixteen  "
                     " Seventeen "
                     " Eighteen "
                     " Nineteen " };

    string tens[] = {" Twenty "
                     " Thirty "
                     " Fourty  "
                     " Fifty   "
                     " Sixty   "
                     " Seventy "
                     " Eighty  "
                     " Ninety  "};
do{
    cout << "Enter any integer value:  " << endl;
    cin >> Number;

    if ( Number <= 0 || Number >= 100 )
    {
        cout << "The number is not between 1 and 99" << endl;
    }
    else ( Number >= 1 && Number <= 19 )
    {
        cout << "The number you have entered is: " << ones[Number] << endl;
    }
    else ( Number >= 20 && Number <= 99)
    {
        leftDigit = Number / 10;
        rightDigit = Number % 10;

        cout << "The number you have entered is: " << tens[leftDigit - 2 ] << " " << ones[rightDigit] << endl;
    }
  } while (yes == 1);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you enter `20`, what does it output?

Comment: This code won't compile. You need to put `else if(..) {..}`.

Comment: I added the if to both the else's and it outputs all the English numbers from string tens[]

Comment: You've dropped a couple of ifs, so the code doesn't compile.

You've dropped the commas separate the string values in the two arrays, so the compiler assumes its all one long string broken over several lines.

Finally, if the input is a multiple of 10, the last 0 shouldn't be printed, e.g. "twenty zero", that is you have a logic error in your program.

Answer (score 4):

You have two issues in your code:

**First**, you need to put commas between your parameters in `string ones[]` and  `string tens[]` like this:

```
string tens[] = { " Twenty ",
        " Thirty ",
        " Fourty  ",
        " Fifty   ",
        " Sixty   ",
        " Seventy ",
        " Eighty  ",
        " Ninety  " };
```

**Second**, you need to add the `if` in every `else`, like this:

```
// ..
else if (Number >= 1 && Number <= 19)
                {
                    cout << "The number you have entered is: " << ones[Number] << endl;
                }
// ..
```

**Result** of your code after fixing these two issues:

[image]

Comment: Glad we were able to help :)

Comment: @Haris How then did you ever get to `Whenever I input a number like 20 it doesn't output Twenty like it should.`? If you couldn't compile the program, you were never able to enter the number "20".

Comment: Twenty Zero? Really?

Comment: @Rudy Well the design is up to the OP. But yeah it does not make sense :)